# How to add conditional formatting to SharePoint list in SharePoint Designer 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, formatting, conditional-statements, preview, designer

I am adding conditional formatting to some columns of a list to change the color of some dates. I'm stuck because I am displaying the lists in preview panes on the page and the conditional formatting is not applying in this view. I am only able to have my formatting work when the list is being shown on the page in a view where the data is static. Hope that makes some sense. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The "Preview Pane" list view style cannot be formatted using SharePoint Designer's conditional formatting option. It's much too different from a typical, tabular list view.

An alternative would be to add JavaScript to the page that would run regularly and apply styles to elements based on their content.

Another (development-heavy) alternative would be to build your own list view using the JavaScript client object model (or XLST if you're feeling masochistic), giving you full control over how the results are displayed.